# how to ignore x509 certificate on Mac terminal

Tags: docker, mac-osx

I am on my local terminal in Mac, and I am trying to login to this harbor repo - https://:50003 I have added server ip to /etc/hosts file. I have added this server entry as insecure registry in daemon.json file

Now when I do docker login , this error comes up

`

```
docker login servername:50003
 Username: developer

 Password:
 
Error response from daemon: Get "https://server01:50003/v2/": x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead`
Login to repo on WEBUI works though after ignoring cert error
```

Now I know that there are 2 options here

ignore this cert check
generate and add CA cert to my local machine.
I am interested in trying the first one, but I am not sure how do I disable cert check. Can someone please help

I have found this so far, export GODEBUG="x509ignoreCN=0"

this is not working. Mac OS is 13.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `'unsigned'` destination certificate to your MacOS Keychain and flag it as trusted.

Comment: thank you for answering, I don't have the certificate with me, where can i get it?

Comment: You could use ''curl'' to download the certificat from the server you try to connect to. Here is a example: openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.edu:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem

Comment: thank you, I was able to download the certificate and add it to my key chain, but I am still seeing the error.

Comment: Try this also: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/